# How to get most frequent value from first 3 row in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

In my PHPMyAdmin database, I have a table named "myTable" consisting of columns u_id, u_name, and u_value. The u_value column contains duplicate entries. My objective is to determine the most frequently occurring value within the first three rows (rows 1 to 3) based on the u_value column.

```
| u_id | u_name | u_value |
|:---- |:------:| -------:|
| 1    | Mr.xyz | A       |
| 2    | Mr.xyz | B       |
| 3    | Mr.xyz | B       |
| 4    | Mr.xyz | A       |
```

I am seeking a PHPMyAdmin SQL query that can effectively retrieve the most common u_value from the initial three rows. How can I construct such a query to fulfill this requirement?

Comment: I think you mean latest values inserted into the database. If that is correct you need to add the timestamp of the insert and then you can use order by on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to get it with only one query. But you can do with two. First get most frequent value:

```
SELECT u_value, COUNT(u_value) AS u_value_count 
FROM myTable
WHERE u_id >= 1 AND u_id <=3
GROUP BY u_value
ORDER BY u_value_count DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Then by using this value you can build another query like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
WHERE u_value = returned_value
ORDER BY u_id LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but i need only most frequent u_values of first 3 row

Comment: like in this example the most occurring value is B in the first 3 row...so i think you got what i want

Comment: You need to get B as a single value or whole columns that have B in this case?

Comment: Ahaaaa,that's what i want...you nailed it!!!❤